# CakePHP 2.5 dynamic model validation: no flash messages

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

i am rewriting my contact form plugin for CakePHP <= 2.2

In the model there are virtual fields only without database table.
For dynamic use, i need to add validation on the fly with `$this->Model->validator()->add()` in the `beforeFilter()` function.

This works, but I don't get any validation errors in the view.
They are stored in `$this->Model->validationErrors` after calling `$this->Model->validates()` only.

When I move the validation into the `$validate` variable everything seems to work.
Flush messages and the "required" attributes in my input fields are set.

I think the problem is rendering the view before adding the validation rules to the model.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Thanks Gergo for editing :)

Comment: I don't think I understand why you can't just validate the normal way, by putting the validation rules in the $validate property..?

Comment: I am trying to make the Plugin more convenient for others so they only have to modify the config variable for the Plugin in bootstrap.php

Comment: Could you change the constructor of the model so that it will add the right validation rule directly to its $validate property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kai for the idea!

This works in the model:

```
public $validate = array();

public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct();
    foreach(Configure::read('ContactForm.Fields') as $fieldname => $value) {
        $this->validate[$fieldname] = $value['validation'];
    }
}
```

The config looks like this:

```
Configure::write('ContactForm.Fields', array(
    'Name' => array(
        'schema' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'null' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'length' => '50'
        ),
        'validation' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'please insert your name'
        )
    )
));
```

Flash messages are visible now ;)